# thymeleaf template class - Could not parse as expression

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have this template that is working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/images/logo.png}" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>Mystic River</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/responsive.css}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent" id="header-wrapper">
....
</html>
```

but when using

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/images/logo.png}" type="image/x-icon"/>
   <title>Mystic River</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/responsive.css}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header th:class="header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent" id="header-wrapper">
```

I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent" (template: "index" - line 14, col 13)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent" (template: "index" - line 14, col 13)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
class="header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent"
```

in the first template and

```
th:class="header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent"
```

in the second (notice the `th:class` instead of `class`).  `"header-wrapper header_fixed bg_transparent"` is not a valid Thymeleaf expression.